Zimbra - message delivered but not visible in inbox
Using Zimbra, user a@domain.com tries to forward a specific message to b@domain.com and x@external.com.
x@esternal.com receives the message, while b@domain.com doesn't.
This is the relevant part of postfix log (/var/log/zimbra.log):
01 mail saslauthd[4025]: auth_zimbra: a@domain.com auth OK
02 mail postfix/smtps/smtpd[3499]: NOQUEUE: filter: RCPT from mail.isp.com[111.222.111.222]: <a@domain.com>: Sender address triggers FILTER smtp-amavis:[127.0.0.1]:10026; from=<a@domain.com> to=<x@external.com> proto=ESMTP helo=<PC>
03 mail postfix/smtps/smtpd[3499]: 5CD5C3C1EB7: client=mail.isp.com[111.222.111.222], sasl_method=LOGIN, sasl_username=a@domain.com
04 mail postfix/cleanup[22522]: 5CD5C3C1EB7: message-id=<!&!AAAAAAAAAAAuAAAAAAAAAOsMsPfjKzNIm/NSOkh5GOABAMO2jhD3dRHOtM0AqgC7tuYAAAAAAA4AABAAAABC5R90F26dQ5eggwL7g+EGAQAAAAA=@domain.com>
05 mail postfix/qmgr[4136]: 5CD5C3C1EB7: from=<a@domain.com>, size=43971, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
06 mail amavis[18432]: (18432-13) ESMTP::10026 /opt/zimbra/data/amavisd/tmp/amavis-20240717T095639-18432-HkZWgX9U: <a@domain.com> -> <x@external.com> Received: from mail.domain.com ([127.0.0.1]) by localhost (mail.domain.com [127.0.0.1]) (amavisd-new, port 10026) with ESMTP for <x@external.com>; Wed, 17 Jul 2024 11:31:00 +0200 (CEST)
07 mail postfix/smtps/smtpd[3499]: NOQUEUE: filter: RCPT from mail.isp.com[111.222.111.222]: <a@domain.com>: Sender address triggers FILTER smtp-amavis:[127.0.0.1]:10026; from=<a@domain.com> to=<b@domain.com> proto=ESMTP helo=<PC>
08 mail postfix/smtps/smtpd[3499]: 779653C1EC2: client=mail.isp.com[111.222.111.222], sasl_method=LOGIN, sasl_username=a@domain.com
09 mail amavis[18432]: (18432-13) Checking: 4nuxFdBrZsAs ORIGINATING [111.222.111.222] <a@domain.com> -> <x@external.com>
10 mail postfix/cleanup[22522]: 779653C1EC2: message-id=<!&!AAAAAAAAAAAuAAAAAAAAAOsMsPfjKzNIm/NSOkh5GOABAMO2jhD3dRHOtM0AqgC7tuYAAAAAAA4AABAAAABC5R90F26dQ5eggwL7g+EGAQAAAAA=@domain.com>
11 mail postfix/qmgr[4136]: 779653C1EC2: from=<a@domain.com>, size=41544, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
12 mail amavis[22915]: (22915-02) ESMTP::10026 /opt/zimbra/data/amavisd/tmp/amavis-20240717T112833-22915-6fNPalUZ: <a@domain.com> -> <b@domain.com> Received: from mail.domain.com ([127.0.0.1]) by localhost (mail.domain.com [127.0.0.1]) (amavisd-new, port 10026) with ESMTP for <b@domain.com>; Wed, 17 Jul 2024 11:31:00 +0200 (CEST)
13 mail amavis[22915]: (22915-02) Checking: HDPTCo_sfiU2 ORIGINATING [111.222.111.222] <a@domain.com> -> <b@domain.com>
14 mail postfix/dkimmilter/smtpd[24846]: connect from localhost[127.0.0.1]
15 mail postfix/dkimmilter/smtpd[24846]: A71233C1ED5: client=localhost[127.0.0.1]
16 mail postfix/cleanup[22522]: A71233C1ED5: message-id=<!&!AAAAAAAAAAAuAAAAAAAAAOsMsPfjKzNIm/NSOkh5GOABAMO2jhD3dRHOtM0AqgC7tuYAAAAAAA4AABAAAABC5R90F26dQ5eggwL7g+EGAQAAAAA=@domain.com>
17 mail postfix/dkimmilter/smtpd[24850]: connect from localhost[127.0.0.1]
18 mail postfix/dkimmilter/smtpd[24850]: B5A013C1EDE: client=localhost[127.0.0.1]
19 mail postfix/cleanup[24852]: B5A013C1EDE: message-id=<!&!AAAAAAAAAAAuAAAAAAAAAOsMsPfjKzNIm/NSOkh5GOABAMO2jhD3dRHOtM0AqgC7tuYAAAAAAA4AABAAAABC5R90F26dQ5eggwL7g+EGAQAAAAA=@domain.com>
20 mail postfix/qmgr[4136]: A71233C1ED5: from=<a@domain.com>, size=44449, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
21 mail amavis[18432]: (18432-13) FWD from <a@domain.com> -> <x@external.com>,BODY=7BIT 250 2.0.0 from MTA(smtp:[127.0.0.1]:10030): 250 2.0.0 Ok: queued as A71233C1ED5
22 mail postfix/dkimmilter/smtpd[24846]: disconnect from localhost[127.0.0.1]
23 mail amavis[16659]: (16659-13) ESMTP::10032 /opt/zimbra/data/amavisd/tmp/amavis-20240717T095519-16659-fTrXengy: <a@domain.com> -> <x@external.com> SIZE=44449 Received: from mail.domain.com ([127.0.0.1]) by localhost (mail.domain.com [127.0.0.1]) (amavisd-new, port 10032) with ESMTP for <x@external.com>; Wed, 17 Jul 2024 11:31:00 +0200 (CEST)
24 mail amavis[18432]: (18432-13) Passed CLEAN {RelayedOutbound}, ORIGINATING LOCAL [111.222.111.222]:58818 [111.222.111.222] <a@domain.com> -> <x@external.com>, Queue-ID: 5CD5C3C1EB7, Message-ID: <!&!AAAAAAAAAAAuAAAAAAAAAOsMsPfjKzNIm/NSOkh5GOABAMO2jhD3dRHOtM0AqgC7tuYAAAAAAA4AABAAAABC5R90F26dQ5eggwL7g+EGAQAAAAA=@domain.com>, mail_id: 4nuxFdBrZsAs, Hits: -, size: 43969, queued_as: A71233C1ED5, 327 ms
25 mail postfix/smtp[22524]: 5CD5C3C1EB7: to=<x@external.com>, relay=127.0.0.1[127.0.0.1]:10026, delay=0.43, delays=0.1/0/0/0.33, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (250 2.0.0 from MTA(smtp:[127.0.0.1]:10030): 250 2.0.0 Ok: queued as A71233C1ED5)
26 mail postfix/qmgr[4136]: 5CD5C3C1EB7: removed
27 mail postfix/qmgr[4136]: B5A013C1EDE: from=<a@domain.com>, size=42030, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
28 mail postfix/dkimmilter/smtpd[24850]: disconnect from localhost[127.0.0.1]
29 mail amavis[22915]: (22915-02) FWD from <a@domain.com> -> <b@domain.com>,BODY=7BIT 250 2.0.0 from MTA(smtp:[127.0.0.1]:10030): 250 2.0.0 Ok: queued as B5A013C1EDE
30 mail amavis[22915]: (22915-02) Passed CLEAN {RelayedInternal}, ORIGINATING LOCAL [111.222.111.222]:58818 [111.222.111.222] <a@domain.com> -> <b@domain.com>, Queue-ID: 779653C1EC2, Message-ID: <!&!AAAAAAAAAAAuAAAAAAAAAOsMsPfjKzNIm/NSOkh5GOABAMO2jhD3dRHOtM0AqgC7tuYAAAAAAA4AABAAAABC5R90F26dQ5eggwL7g+EGAQAAAAA=@domain.com>, mail_id: HDPTCo_sfiU2, Hits: -, size: 41541, queued_as: B5A013C1EDE, 277 ms
31 mail postfix/smtp[24845]: 779653C1EC2: to=<b@domain.com>, relay=127.0.0.1[127.0.0.1]:10026, delay=0.37, delays=0.08/0.01/0/0.28, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (250 2.0.0 from MTA(smtp:[127.0.0.1]:10030): 250 2.0.0 Ok: queued as B5A013C1EDE)
32 mail postfix/qmgr[4136]: 779653C1EC2: removed
33 mail postfix/amavisd/smtpd[19821]: disconnect from localhost[127.0.0.1]
34 mail amavis[28964]: (28964-16) ESMTP::10032 /opt/zimbra/data/amavisd/tmp/amavis-20240717T090325-28964-Y_AnmeFF: <a@domain.com> -> <b@domain.com> SIZE=42030 Received: from mail.domain.com ([127.0.0.1]) by localhost (mail.domain.com [127.0.0.1]) (amavisd-new, port 10032) with ESMTP for <b@domain.com>; Wed, 17 Jul 2024 11:31:00 +0200 (CEST)
35 mail amavis[16659]: (16659-13) Checking: Em_elC9HCe6G ORIGINATING_POST/MYNETS [127.0.0.1] <a@domain.com> -> <x@external.com>
36 mail amavis[28964]: (28964-16) Checking: ZELWWAnThK7z ORIGINATING_POST/MYNETS [127.0.0.1] <a@domain.com> -> <b@domain.com>
37 mail postfix/amavisd/smtpd[19821]: connect from localhost[127.0.0.1]
38 mail postfix/amavisd/smtpd[19821]: CA1EE3C1EB7: client=localhost[127.0.0.1]
39 mail postfix/cleanup[22522]: CA1EE3C1EB7: message-id=<!&!AAAAAAAAAAAuAAAAAAAAAOsMsPfjKzNIm/NSOkh5GOABAMO2jhD3dRHOtM0AqgC7tuYAAAAAAA4AABAAAABC5R90F26dQ5eggwL7g+EGAQAAAAA=@domain.com>
40 mail postfix/amavisd/smtpd[19821]: disconnect from localhost[127.0.0.1]
41 mail postfix/qmgr[4136]: CA1EE3C1EB7: from=<a@domain.com>, size=43281, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
42 mail amavis[28964]: (28964-16) FWD from <a@domain.com> -> <b@domain.com>,BODY=7BIT 250 2.0.0 from MTA(smtp:[127.0.0.1]:10025): 250 2.0.0 Ok: queued as CA1EE3C1EB7
43 mail amavis[28964]: (28964-16) Passed CLEAN {RelayedInternal}, ORIGINATING_POST/MYNETS LOCAL [127.0.0.1]:57044 [111.222.111.222] <a@domain.com> -> <b@domain.com>, Queue-ID: B5A013C1EDE, Message-ID: <!&!AAAAAAAAAAAuAAAAAAAAAOsMsPfjKzNIm/NSOkh5GOABAMO2jhD3dRHOtM0AqgC7tuYAAAAAAA4AABAAAABC5R90F26dQ5eggwL7g+EGAQAAAAA=@domain.com>, mail_id: ZELWWAnThK7z, Hits: -0.3, size: 42479, queued_as: CA1EE3C1EB7, dkim_sd=AC39CDEA-990F-11EB-B5A4-AF38199D4FE8:domain.com, 1011 ms
44 mail postfix/smtp[22524]: B5A013C1EDE: to=<b@domain.com>, relay=127.0.0.1[127.0.0.1]:10032, delay=1.1, delays=0.1/0/0.01/1, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (250 2.0.0 from MTA(smtp:[127.0.0.1]:10025): 250 2.0.0 Ok: queued as CA1EE3C1EB7)
45 mail postfix/qmgr[4136]: B5A013C1EDE: removed
46 mail postfix/lmtp[22527]: CA1EE3C1EB7: to=<b@domain.com>, relay=mail.domain.com[109.233.127.200]:7025, delay=0.09, delays=0.01/0/0.03/0.05, dsn=2.1.5, status=sent (250 2.1.5 Delivery OK)
47 mail postfix/qmgr[4136]: CA1EE3C1EB7: removed
48 mail postfix/smtps/smtpd[3499]: disconnect from mail.isp.com[111.222.111.222]
[...]
49 mail postfix/amavisd/smtpd[19821]: 971803C1EB7: client=localhost[127.0.0.1]
50 mail postfix/cleanup[24852]: 971803C1EB7: message-id=<!&!AAAAAAAAAAAuAAAAAAAAAOsMsPfjKzNIm/NSOkh5GOABAMO2jhD3dRHOtM0AqgC7tuYAAAAAAA4AABAAAABC5R90F26dQ5eggwL7g+EGAQAAAAA=@domain.com>
51 mail postfix/qmgr[4136]: 971803C1EB7: from=<a@domain.com>, size=45298, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
52 mail postfix/amavisd/smtpd[19821]: disconnect from localhost[127.0.0.1]
53 mail amavis[16659]: (16659-13) FWD from <a@domain.com> -> <x@external.com>,BODY=7BIT 250 2.0.0 from MTA(smtp:[127.0.0.1]:10025): 250 2.0.0 Ok: queued as 971803C1EB7
54 mail amavis[16659]: (16659-13) Passed CLEAN {RelayedOutbound}, ORIGINATING_POST/MYNETS LOCAL [127.0.0.1]:57042 [121.212.121.212] <a@domain.com> -> <x@external.com>, Queue-ID: A71233C1ED5, Message-ID: <!&!AAAAAAAAAAAuAAAAAAAAAOsMsPfjKzNIm/NSOkh5GOABAMO2jhD3dRHOtM0AqgC7tuYAAAAAAA4AABAAAABC5R90F26dQ5eggwL7g+EGAQAAAAA=@domain.com>, mail_id: Em_elC9HCe6G, Hits: -0.299, size: 44899, queued_as: 971803C1EB7, dkim_sd=AC39CDEA-990F-11EB-B5A4-AF38199D4FE8:domain.com, 4950 ms
55 mail postfix/smtp[24855]: A71233C1ED5: to=<x@external.com>, relay=127.0.0.1[127.0.0.1]:10032, delay=5, delays=0.09/0.01/0/4.9, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (250 2.0.0 from MTA(smtp:[127.0.0.1]:10025): 250 2.0.0 Ok: queued as 971803C1EB7)
56 mail postfix/qmgr[4136]: A71233C1ED5: removed
57 mail postfix/smtp[24865]: 971803C1EB7: to=<x@external.com>, relay=mail.external.com[121.212.121.212]:25, delay=6.6, delays=0.11/0.01/5.1/1.4, dsn=2.6.0, status=sent (250 2.6.0 45296 bytes received in 00:00:01; Message id 202407171131116766 accepted for delivery)
58 mail postfix/qmgr[4136]: 971803C1EB7: removed

I guess that in the end the most relevant lines are 46 and 57, where I see that both messages have been delevered.
Yet, b@domain.com can't see the message.
I had a look at other log files (clamd.log, mailbox.log, etc) but I can't find any reference to this message.
Some other useful info:

The message is rather small, b@domain.com has no quota issues and server has plenity of space.
A brand new message from a@domain.com to b@domain.com is correctly delivered.
The same message received by x@external.com and forwarded to b@domain.com is correctly delivered.
The problematic message forwarded from a@domain.com to b@domain.com WITHOUT additional recipients is NOT delivered.

How can I track down this issue to see where the message gets deleted? Are there any other relevant log files I'm not aware of?
Thank you!

I found out that the user had an option enabled that says "Automatically delete duplicate copies of the same message when received":

The problematic message wasn't identical to other ones, but is a forward of a previous message already received by the user, maybe this confused Zimbra.
By disabling this option the issue is resolved.
